# Spring JPA OneToMany collection not deleting entry

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete an entry from multiple OneToMany relationships, however no matter what I do it does not update the collection.

I have three classes, Rating, Content and User. I can successfully create ratings which properly populates the content and user collections. However, I can not delete ratings from the collections. The rating get successfully deleted, however the content and user collections don't get updated. Below are the three classes:

```
public class Rating {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
    private Content content;

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        if (!user.getRatings().contains(this)) {
            user.getRatings().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
        if (!content.getRatings().contains(this)) {
            content.getRatings().add(this);
        }
    } 
}

public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        this.ratings.add(rating);
        if (rating.getUser() != this) {
            rating.setUser(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.remove(rating);
    } 
}

public class Content {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        this.ratings.add(rating);
        if (rating.getContent() != this) {
            rating.setContent(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.remove(rating);
    } 
}

public class RatingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/ratings/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteRating(@PathVariable("id") int ratingId) {
        Rating rating = ratingService.getRatingById(ratingId);

        if (rating == null) {
            return;
        }

        // THIS DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
        rating.getUser().removeRating(rating);

        // THIS DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
        rating.getContent().removeRating(rating);

        ratingService.deleteRating(rating);
    } 
}
```

Even when manually removing from the collections it still does not update.  Any ideas?

Comment: I implemented both hashCode() and equlas() for all three classes and the collections are still not updating. (I used IntelliJ generator with guaranteed unique non-null fields)

Comment: Actually the content's ratings are getting updated, but for some reason the user's isn't. Weird, I'll take a closer look at why

Comment: Thank you Xtreme Biker, that worked.

Comment: Sure, if you want too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks kind of you have neither a proper `hashCode()` or `equals()` method for your `Rating` class. Java can't find the one you want to delete and thus it's not getting removed.

You could write an `EntityBase` from which all the classes will have this common code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }
    return ComparisonChain.start().compare(getId(), ((EntityBase) obj).getId()).result() == 0;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (getId() == null) ? super.hashCode() : getId().intValue();
}
```

**See also:**

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html